# git push error: src refspec main does not match any on linux

Tags: git, github, branch, git-refspec

whenever I'm trying to upload my files using `git push -u origin main`
I'm getting error which is as follows

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxxxxx/xxx-project.git'
```

but if I do `git push -u origin master` it is working perfectly and uploading my files to a separate branch named `master`. upon checking  `.git/refs/heads` in my project i saw that there is only one file named `master` so i performed `git remote update` which added `.git/refs/remotes/origin/main` but still `git push -u origin main` didn't work.

I tried `git push origin HEAD:main` but produced error:

`! [rejected]        HEAD -> main (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxxxxxx/xxx-project.git' hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

I want to push my code to main branch using `git push -u origin main`. how do I do that ?

P.S - git version 2.29.2, pop_os 20.10.1

Edit1 - `git push -f origin HEAD:main` pushes my code to `main` branch but how can i replace `master` file with `main` file in `refs/heads` so that i don't have to mention head and force my push ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a multi-part answer because there are two separate issues here that are tangling together now.  Here's a summary of what we'll cover:

- `main` vs `master`
- `error: src refspec main does not match any`
- reconciling separate `main` and `master` branches

Each of these is in its own section.

## `main` vs `master`

Git itself has no special branch names.<sup>1</sup>  You could use `main`, `master`, `trunk`, or any other name as the name of your first branch.  Git has traditionally used the name `master` here, but there is a project to make this configurable, so that if you are French or Spanish you can use the name `principal` or `première` or `primero`, or if you prefer Maori, you can use `matua` or `tuatahi`.  Currently, you can do this manually during or after a `git init`,<sup>2</sup> but the project makes Git just do it automatically, without requiring a second step: If for *any* reason you want *any* other name by default, you can configure that.

Meanwhile, GitHub have already chosen to leap ahead and make their default initial branch name `main` instead of `master`.  But this leaves *your* Git and *GitHub's* Git out of sync, as it were.  For more about GitHub's changeover, see
[Difference Between Main Branch and Master Branch in Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64249491/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some technical flaws in this kind of claim.  As we know, [technically correct is the best kind of correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/48a9bw/why_is_technically_correct_the_best_kind_of/), so let me add a few caveats in this footnote:

- Merging auto-generates a message of the form `merge branch X into Y` when you are on branch *`Y`* and run `git merge X`.  However, when you're on `master`, Git traditionally generates only a message of the form `merge branch X`.
- A new, empty repository created by `git init` has no commits and therefore has no branches (because a branch can only exist by having commits on it).  However, you must be *on* some branch in this new empty repository.  So Git stores some name in the symbolic ref named `HEAD`.  This is the branch name that you're on, even if that branch name does not exist (yet).  For a long time, Git has had, hard-coded into it, some code to stick the branch name `master` in there.  (This is, in effect, what GitHub changed.)
- There are a bunch of other string literals reading `master` in the source and documentation as well; they're being converted to use the configuration settings but this will all take time.

<sup>2</sup>If you have Git 2.28 or later, run `git init --initial-branch=name`, and/or set `init.defaultBranch` with `git config` in your system or global configuration.  If you have an earlier version of Git installed, or have already run `git init`, simply use `git branch -m` to rename `master` to whatever name you like.

---

## `error: src refspec main does not match any`

This error message from Git is quite cryptic to newbies, but is actually pretty simple.  The problems are that it's loaded with jargon ([webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon); [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon)), and abbreviates "source" to "src".

Git is all about commits.  When we *clone* a repository, we have our Git reach out to some other Git.  That other Git looks up a repository, and that other repository is full of commits.  We then have our Git create a new repository locally, transfer into it *all* of their commits, and turn all of their *branch names* into *remote-tracking names*.  Then our Git creates, in this new repository, *one* branch name, based on one of their branch names.  At least, that's the normal process.  (And, if you know what all these terms mean, good!  If not, don't worry too much about them right now.  The point to remember here is that we get *all their commits* and *none of their branches*, and then we normally have our Git *create* one branch to match one of theirs.)

Since Git is all about commits, this process—of copying all their commits, but only copying one of their branch names to a name spelled the same in our own repository—is all we need.  The fact that our Git *renames all of their branch names*—so that with the one exception, we don't have any branches at all—isn't normally very important.  Our own Git deals with this later, automatically, if and when it's necessary.

When we use `git push`, we are asking our Git program, which is reading our own Git repository, to connect to some other Git program—typically running on a server machine—that can then write to some other Git repository.  We'd like our Git to send their Git some of our commits.  In particular, we want to send them *our **new** commits:* the ones we just made.  Those are, after all, where we put all our good new stuff.  (Git is all about commits, so that's the only place we can put anything.)

Once we've sent these commits, though, we need to their Git to set one of *their* branch names to *remember* our new commits.  That's because the way Git *finds* commits is to use branch names.<sup>3</sup>  The real names of each commit are big ugly hash ID numbers, which nobody wants to remember or look at; so we have Git remember these numbers using the branch names.  That way, we only have to look at the branch names, and these names can be meaningful to us: `trunk`, or `feature/tall`, or `tuatahi`, or whatever.

By default and convention, the way we do this using `git push` is pretty simple:

```
git push origin main
```

for instance.  The `git push` part is the command that means *send commits and ask them to set a name*.  The `origin` part is what Git calls a *remote:* a short name that, mostly, holds a URL.  The `main` part at the end, here, is *our* branch name.  That's the one *our* Git is using to find *our commits*.  We'll have our Git send our commits, then ask their Git to set *their* `main` too.

This last part—where we've put in `main` here—is what Git calls a *refspec*.  Refspecs actually let us put in *two* names, separated by a colon, or a couple of other forms.  We can, for instance, use `HEAD:main` as in [Arka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65173712/1256452) (although for technical reasons we might want to use `HEAD:refs/heads/main` in many cases).  But in simple cases, we can just use one branch name: `git push origin main`.  The simple branch name is a simple form of refspec.

**For this to work, the source name must be the name of an existing branch in our own Git repository.**  This is where things are going wrong.

(See also [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181861/1256452P))

---

<sup>3</sup>Git can use *any* name, not just a branch name.  For instance, a tag name works fine.  But this answer is about branch names because the *question* is about branch names, and branch names are the most common ones to use here.

---

#### What if *our* Git created only `master`?

Suppose we're using GitHub and we've asked GitHub to make a *new repository* for us.  They run a form of `git init` that supplies, as the new repository's initial branch name, the name `main`.  They may or may not create one commit, too.  Let's say we do have them create this one commit.  That one commit will hold `README` and/or `LICENSE` files, based on what we choose using the web interface.  Creating that initial commit actually creates the branch name `main`.

If we now *clone* their repository, we'll get their one commit, which will be under their branch name `main`.  Our Git will rename their `main` to `origin/main` and then create one new branch name, `main`, to match theirs.  So all will be good.

But, if we create our own *empty* Git repository, using `git init` ourselves, our Git may set us up so that our first commit will create the name `master`.  We *won't have a `main` branch:* we'll have a `master` branch instead.

Or, if we don't have GitHub create an initial *commit*, the GitHub repository will be totally empty.  Because it has no commits, it has no branches: a branch name is only allowed to exist if it specifies some commit.  So if we clone this empty repository, we'll have no branches either, and our Git won't know to use `main`: our Git may instead use `master`.  We're back in that same situation, where our Git think the first name to create should be `master`.

So, in these various situations, we make our first commit(s), and they all go on a branch named `master`.  If we now run:

```
git push -u origin main
```

(with or without the `-u`; I won't go into the details about the `-u` here) our Git looks around in our Git repository for a branch named `main`.  There isn't one!  So our Git just gives us that:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
```

error message.

To fix this, we can either `git push origin master`—which sends our commits and then asks GitHub to create a new branch in the GitHub repository, with that branch name being `master`—or rename our `master` to whatever name we wanted, and then use that name:

```
git branch -m master xyzzy
git push -u origin xyzzy
```

will make the (single) branch name that we both use be `xyzzy`.  If you want `main` here, rename your `master` to `main`.

## What if you've accidentally made both branches?

Suppose we used GitHub to create a new repository, with their new default branch name `main`, that includes one initial commit with the usual README and LICENSE files.  Then, without thinking about it, we used `git init` on our own machine to create our own new repository, with its default branch name `master`, and we made a commit or two on our `master`.

If we now rename our `master` to `main`:

```
git branch -m master main
```

and then try to push:

```
git push -u origin main
```

we get a *different* error:

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
```

The reason for this is simple enough: *They* have a commit, that they find using *their* name `main`, that we do not have.  If they change their name `main` to find the last commit that we're sending them, they'll *lose* the *initial commit* they made, with the README and LICENSE files.

You have a bunch of options here:

- You can ignore the initial commit they made.  It's just a boilerplate commit, after all.  You can tell them to throw it away entirely.  Use `git push --force` as outlined in any of many existing StackOverflow answers.
- You can obtain their initial commit and *rebase* your commits on those commits.  This can be slightly tricky, because your first commit is a *root commit*.  If your first commit contains README and/or LICENSE files, you'll get an add/add conflict here.  In this case it's probably simpler to just force-push.
- You can obtain their initial commit and *merge* your commits.  In a modern Git, this requires using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option.  As with the rebase method, if your commits contain README and/or LICENSE files, you'll get add/add conflicts.  The resulting repository will also have two root commits.  None of these are serious problems, but they might prove slightly annoying.

To obtain their commit, simply run `git fetch origin`.  That will get GitHub's first commit, and use the name `origin/main` in your own Git repository to remember it.  You can then:

```
git rebase origin/main
```

or:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/main
```

to achieve the rebase or merge.  You can choose whether to rename your branch to `main`, if you have not already done so, at any time before or after doing all of this.

Comment: first of all thank you for your detailed explanations. I didn't expected these level of information. I've one more request. please point me to some blogs where I can understand about rebase and root commit.

Comment: Not really sure about blog posts, but there are plenty of answers about rebasing and root commits and such here on StackOverflow, e.g., [Change first commit of project with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246208/1256452) and [How to merge a commit with the next commit in git interactive rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700004/1256452). This question and answer is perhaps more directly relevant though: [Insert a NON-EMPTY commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59548124/1256452)

Comment: Note that you can search StackOverflow using the search bar *on* StackOverflow: put `[git]` in literally, within the square brackets, and then various keywords, and SO will search their own questions and answers for those keywords with the [tag:git] tag on the original question.

Comment: Wow this is an article!

Comment: Fantastic answer. In my particular case the solution to the `error: src refspec main does not match any` error was even simpler - I hadn't committed anything yet, so running ` git commit -m "Initial commit" ` resolved this for me. Just adding this here in case anyone else overlooked this simple step like I did.

Comment: Man the level of detail in this answer is top quality. Keep up the great work. I have used git for years, but as you pointed out, our local tooling typically "helps" hide some of the finder details. Would give you multiple upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 49):

I have stuck in a similar issue a few hours ago but have eventually figured out why the error keeps coming and the solution to it.

**What I did:**

- I created a git repository at GitHub
- Initialized my project in my code editor(vs code) as a git repository
- I added the URL to my repo using

  ```
  git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx.git
  ```

By this time

```
git remote -v
```

probably gave as expected

```
origin  https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git (push)
```

Notice that

```
git branch
```

will show you **nothing** at this point because you have not created any branch also you cannot be able to create any.

**The issue:**

When I tried

```
git push -u origin main
```

I got

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git'
```

Even with the git recommended command

```
git push --set-upstream origin master (or main preferably)
```

I got the same error.

**Now the solution:**

Add a file in your project such as README.md

```
git add .
git commit -m "added README.md"
git branch -M main
```

The -M is to rename your branch if you don't want it to be called master

Finally,

```
git push origin main
```

Comment: thanks! this solved my entire issue

Comment: minimum effort, maximum satisfaction! pretty strange issue, never had problem before with this, but your solution was amazing :) thank you

Comment: `git remote -v` it solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
git add .
```

If done already, try to commit:

```
git commit -m "First commit for example..."
git branch -M main
```

and finally:

```
git push origin main
```

Comment: this answer should be further up, as forgetting to commit also causes the issue.

Answer (score 8):

after researching a bit more and coming up empty, I tried a hack. here it is.

after `git push -f origin HEAD:main` i completely deleted my local project folder  then cloned my project from main branch. now i can use `git push origin main` to push any changes i want. i checked and now there's a `main` file in `.git/refs/heads` location of my project.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  It seems that `-f` is the magical override flag that forces git to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 5):

If this is the first time you are pushing to the main branch follow these step after committing your changes.
I faced this error error:

```
src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<my_project_name>.git
```

and I fixed using these steps after commit.Change URL for your github in the following code:

```
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/Sidrah-Madiha/<my_project_url>.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: I get an error: **! [rejected]        main -> refs/heads/main (already exists)**

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630404/git-push-refs-heads-my-subbranch-exists-cannot-create, seems like  you are using `git branch main` instead of `git branch -M main`

Comment: But now I get an error: **fatal: remote origin already exists.**

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue, please make sure, you have used `git add .` or instead of . in the command add the files you want to commit then use `git commit -m "your message for commit" ` then use all the command above from `git branch -M main`,let me know if this fixes your issue

Comment: I fixed my issue using force `-f` flag when pushing.  That is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was simply trying to push an empty folder.
Added test.txt file and all is working!

Here is what I used:

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin https://.../repo.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked adding this to the `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  User <your username>
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Note: `id_ed25519.pub` is added in my github authorized SSH keys

Answer (score 0):

It might also occur that you cloned your repo from a master branch and now you are trying to commit it to the main branch. If your local repo is in the master branch and you are trying to commit it to the main branch on your remote repo then try using the following command.

`git push -f origin master:main`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but this command solved the problem:

```bash
git branch -M main
```